# Бесконечное перемещение через jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Нужно сделать так чтобы тайловое изображение внутри блока перемещалось бесконечно.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#intro').animate({backgroundPositionX: 'эта величина должна увеличивать бесконечно'}, 40000,'linear');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

У animate есть callback, можно использовать его как-то так.  Использую для наглядности свойство margin-left

```js
$(function() {
   Animation ();
})

function Animation () {
   $('#intro').animate({marginLeft: parseInt($('#intro').css("marginLeft"))+1+"px"}, 10,'linear', Animation);
}
```

```css
#intro {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="intro"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#intro').animate({
      backgroundPositionX: x + 'px'
    }, 100, 'linear');
    x++;
  }, 400);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Анимация создания таким способом получается дёрганная

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как jQuery не поддерживает анимацию *backgroundPosition*. Может в новых версиях уже работает... Я использую **jQuery Background Position**: http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html Можно сделать что-то вроде такого:

```
    $(#intro).animate({backgroundPosition: '+=1% +=1%'}, 40000);
```

Выставите большее время, тогда будет «бесконечность». :-)